# Change JSON structure while iterating over it

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have JSON that I'm parsing in Python, it looks something like this

```json
{
  "New Slim Testing":{
    "name":"New Slim Testing",
    "id":"6496",
    "type":1,
    "fullpath":"\\New Slim Testing",
    "children": {
        "sf_account":{
          "name":"sf_account",
          "type":1,
          "fullpath":"",
          "id":"6516"
        },
        "sf_case":{
          "name":"sf_case",
          "type":1,
          "fullpath":"",
          "id":"6517",
          "children": {
              "sf_case_delete":{
                "name":"sf_case_delete",
                "type":1,
                "fullpath":"",
                "id":"6518"
              }
            }
        },
        "sync_incr_sfdc_b2b_to_rds_sf_case":{
          "name":"sync_incr_sfdc_b2b_to_rds_sf_case",
          "type":2,
          "fullpath":"",
          "command":"&lt;T4I_DNA_SCRIPTS.23&gt;run_infacloud_task.ksh",
          "parameters":"0 &lt;JobName&gt; DSS",
          "id":"6520"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This JSON will be used to make API calls. Although id is hard-coded at the moment, it is supposed to be dynamic and be returned by the API call. How do I change some values in this dictionary while iterating over it?

For example: parent job will be created, it will get assigned an id and when creating child job I will make use of its parent id and so on and so forth.

Same is true for fullpath field. I want to derive it at runtime (iterating dictionary) rather than hard-coding it.

Here is what I'm trying to do

```
def jsonTraverser(json,parentJson):

    templateXML = settings.JOBXMLTEMPLATE

    for key, val in json.items():
        if isinstance(val, dict):
            pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=2)
            if(key!="children"):
                parentId = parentJson["id"]
                fullpath = '{}\\{}'.format(parentJson["fullpath"],json[key]["name"])
                print('Fullpath is {}'.format(fullpath))
                json['fullpath'] = fullpath
                if val['type']==1:
                    print('Creating job group {}'.format(val["name"]))
                    createJob(val,parentId)
                else:
                    print('Creating job {}'.format(val["name"]))
                    createJob(val,parentId)
            jsonTraverser(val,json)
```

I am getting the error : dictionary changed size during iteration

Comment: Json is not a datatype, it's a text format. Once deserialized what you have is a simple Python object, most of the time (as is the case here) a plain `dict`. So learn to use Python dicts (and lists etc) and you'll be done.

Comment: Why would you want to "iterate" over the JSON? Consider reading the JSON string into a dictionary and then editing values there.

Comment: Yeah by editing JSON that's what I meant to say, I have deserialized it into Python dictionary, how to do I change the values in this dictionary while iterating over it. The error that I get it ```dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Comment: Please provide some code of what have you tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Use independent keys of your json data by `list(dct.keys())`(list is for python3+):

```
In [5]: dct = {1: 2, 2: 3}

In [6]: for k in list(dct.keys()):
   ...:     dct[str(k)] = dct[k]
   ...:

In [7]: dct
Out[7]: {1: 2, 2: 3, '1': 2, '2': 3}
```